# Android asynctask waiting for anotherr asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> ```
>   public class GetFlyers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
> ImageView imageView;
> int imageSize;
> Context context;
> String url="";
> String im="";
> Flyer fly;
> ImageFragment i1;
> int position;
> public GetFlyers(ImageView imageView, int imageSize, Context conext,String im, Flyer flu, ImageFragment i1, int position )
> {
>     this.im = im;
>     this.position = position;
>     this.imageView = imageView;
>     this.imageSize = imageSize;
>     this.context=context;
>     this.i1 = i1;
>     fly = flu;
> }
> protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
>     Bitmap map = null;
>     for (String url : urls) {
>         Log.d("firste","image loaded back");
>         if(url != null && !url.trim().equals(""))
>         {
>             map = downloadImage(url);
>             this.url = url;
>         }
>     }
>     return map;
> }
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {   }
> private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
>     Bitmap bitmap = null;
>     InputStream stream = null;
>     BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>     bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
>     try {
>         stream = getHttpConnection(url);
>         bitmap = BitmapFactory.
>                 decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
>     } catch (IOException e1) {
>         e1.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             stream.close();
>         }
>         catch(Exception e)
>         {
> ```

```
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
// Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConnection.connect();
        if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

}

I have this code, whenever i called this thread... lets say 3 times..
GetFlyers task = new GetFlyers    tasl.execute ... unfortunately one call per a time moves on. only one asynctask goes..i want to run another asynctask while running this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncTasks are executed serially by default starting Honeycomb.

To run AsyncTasks in parallel on all platrorms, run as

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

See

[AsyncTask: Order of Execution](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)

Comment: How many executeOnExecutor can run together? how many threads can run together in android?

Comment: @user3278732 according to AsyncTask source code for Android 19: it's CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1

Comment: does thread pool exectuor handle such things. like if there are many threads, queue one of them to wait for one of the 10 to finish to start the 11th

Comment: The default THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR executes at insertion order, when it reaches MAX, it waits until one of the threads terminates, and then executes next one from the queue until all threads are done. But you can pass any Executor, even your own implementation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html